# Python keyring returns object data on Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, python-keyring

I'm trying to use keyring python module on Mac.

```
keyring.get_password
```

returns None, although I am pretty sure that the keyring and the username in it both exist.  Any idea what could be the problem?

To give a more concrete example, this piece of code:

```
print "'{}' '{}' [{}]".format(KEYRING, username, keyring.get_keyring())
return keyring.get_password(KEYRING, username)
```

prints this when I invoke it with concrete arguments:

```
'login' 'skype' [<keyring.backends.OS_X.Keyring object at 0x10c85b450>]
```

Comment: Can you show us exactly what arguments you’re supplying to `get_password`? You can change the username, but it might be helpful.

Comment: I have updated the original question with an example

Comment: Try storing a password first with `keyring.set_password("myapp", "username", "password")`, then retrieving it with `keyring.get_password("myapp", "username")`